# Conditionally Combine Lambdas in Kotlin for Filtering with Multiple Predicates

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, predicate

Suppose I have the following predicates as predefined lambdas for a Villager POJO.

```
    val matchesSearch: (Villager, String) -> Boolean =
        { villager: Villager, query: String -> villager.name.contains(query) }

    val matchesGender: (Villager, Int) -> Boolean =
        { villager: Villager, filter: Int -> filter == villager.gender }

    val matchesPersonality: (Villager, Int) -> Boolean =
        { villager: Villager, filter: Int -> filter == villager.personality }

    val matchesSpecies: (Villager, Int) -> Boolean =
        { villager: Villager, filter: Int -> filter == villager.species }

    val matchesHobby: (Villager, Int) -> Boolean =
        { villager: Villager, filter: Int -> filter == villager.hobby }
```

I only want to apply the predicate IF a certain condition is met. For example, only filter by gender if a gender filter has been applied. Or I only want to match against the search query if one has been entered.

```
fun getVillagersThatMatchQueryAndFilters(list: List<Villager>): List<Villager> {

    val conditions = ArrayList<Predicate<Villager>>()

    if (searchQuery.isNotEmpty()) {
        // TODO: apply the matchesSearch() predicate lambda
        conditions.add(Predicate { villager -> villager.name.contains(query) })
    }
    if (genderFilter > 0) {
        // TODO: apply the matchesGender() predicate lambda
        conditions.add(Predicate { genderFilter == villager.gender })
    }
    if (personalityFilter > 0) {
        // TODO: apply the matchesPersonality() predicate lambda
        conditions.add(Predicate { personalityFilter == villager.personality })
    }
    if (speciesFilter > 0) {
        // TODO: apply the matchesSpecies() predicate lambda
        conditions.add(Predicate { speciesFilter == villager.species })
    }
    if (hobbyFilter > 0) {
        // TODO: apply the matchesHobby() predicate lambda
        conditions.add(Predicate { hobbyFilter == villager.hobby })
    }

    return list.filter {
        // TODO: match on all conditionally applied predicates
        conditions.allPredicatesCombinedWithAnd() // this doesn't actually exist
    }
}
```

Previously I had done `list.filter{ }` within each condition and applied the necessary predicate, however, since I could have up to 5 predicates being applied, it is quite terrible for performance as it iterates over the list each time `.filter()` is called.

Is there a way to programmatically iterate over a `List<Predicate<T>>` and combine predicates with `.and()` or `&&` so that I may apply the filter ONCE? Or if not, how can I **conditionally combine** these predicates?

I would use the final Java example [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/core-java-modules/core-java-function/src/test/java/com/baeldung/java8/Java8PredicateChainUnitTest.java) that uses `Predicates.stream()` and `Collectors` but it requires Android API level 24 (higher than my current Android min).

**SOLUTION BELOW** - thanks to suggestions from [@Laurence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296641/laurence) and [@IR42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12191177/ir42)

*Works for < Android API 24*

Create a list of the lambdas and conditionally add any predicates that you wish to match list items against. Then use `Collections.Aggregates.all()` method to ensure you are filtering against ALL predicates. (The equivalent of doing `pred1.and(pred2).and(etc.)...` for all items in the list.)

Huge performance saver if you have a large number of predicates to be filtered against as `list.filter()` is only called ONCE.

```
fun getVillagersThatMatchQueryAndFilters(list: List<Villager>): List<Villager> {

    val conditions = ArrayList<(Villager) -> Boolean>()

    if (searchQuery.isNotEmpty()) {
        conditions.add{ it.name.contains(query) }
    }
    if (genderFilter > 0) {
        conditions.add{ genderFilter == it.gender }
    }
    if (personalityFilter > 0) {
        conditions.add{ personalityFilter == it.personality }
    }
    if (speciesFilter > 0) {
        conditions.add{ speciesFilter == it.species }
    }
    if (hobbyFilter > 0) {
        conditions.add{ hobbyFilter == it.hobby }
    }

    return list.filter { candidate -> conditions.all { it(candidate) } }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with creating a new lambda, combining result of both lambda with `&&` for intersection?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I only want to apply certain lambdas if a condition is met. The condition for each lambda is separate, and I have more than 2 (5 in my example) otherwise I would just list out each combination case of predicates. Like `if (a) applyPredicateA()` AND `if (b) applyPredicateB()` AND `if(c)` etc.

Comment: Can you point out any example, input and their expected output, I'm not getting what you want to do.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I added more detail to the question. I want to simplify list filtering by multiple conditional predicates to improve performance.

Comment: `list.filter { conditions.all { pred -> pred.test(it) } }` ?

Comment: @IR42 That worked for me! However, `test()` requires min Android API level 24. Any ideas on a good way to do this for < API 24?

Comment: use lambdas instead of `Predicate` interface, `ArrayList<(Villager)->Boolean>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the [all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) extension function, and as a point of interest the [any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) extension function as well. I think you just have to use them in your filter block on your predicates. Here is a very simple example with a silly set of predicates:

```
fun main() {
    val thingsToFilter = listOf(-1,2,5)

    val predicates = listOf(
        { value: Int -> value > 0 },
        { value: Int -> value > 4 }
    )

    val filtered = thingsToFilter.filter {candidate ->
        predicates.all{ it(candidate)}
    }

    print(filtered) // Outputs [5]

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Building upon Laurence's answer, you can create an extension like this

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.filterAll(vararg predicates: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    return filter { candidate ->
        predicates.all { it(candidate) }
    }
}
```